# Force order of dependencies in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that i want to use in parallel to compile a set of separate programs. It looks something like this:

```
compileall: program1 program2 program3
    @echo "Compilation completed"

program1 program2 program3:
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

I call it using `gmake compileall -j3` and everything works fine. It runs daily as a part of our testing script.

Now, I've added a new target `program1a` that needs to be a part of this same make target and must not be performed at the same time as the `program1` target. It is not important if it happens before or after, just not in parallel.

I know I could do something like:

```
compileall:
    +$(MAKE) program1 program2 program3
    +$(MAKE) program1a
    @echo "Compilation completed"

program1 program2 program3:
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(MAKE) -C $@

program1a:
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(MAKE) -C program1 A=true
```

Is there a better way to do this? I would like to not have to wait for the `program2` and `program3` to finish in order to start `program1a` compilation.

Comment: Is the `-c` option meant to be `-C` option ? And in your first snippet, you're always compiling `program1` no matter what your target is.

Comment: Why not just make `program1` be a prerequisite for `program1a`?   Then make will be required to finish program1 before starting program1a.

Comment: @Chnossos I've fixed the syntax in the snippets, thanks.
@lornix That means that I can't compile just `program1a`, I would have to compile `program1` as well

Comment: Have you tried the [`.NOTPARALLEL:`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets) special target name?

Answer (score 2):

Not tested (tell me if this does not work), but you could do something like this :

```make
compileall: program1 program2 program3
    @echo "Compilation completed"

program1: program1a
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(MAKE) -C $@

program1a program2 program3:
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

That way `program1a` should be built before `program1` and make should be able to build `program2` and `program3` in parallel anyway.

---

**EDIT**: A little bit cleaner (thx @Beta):

```make
compileall: program1 program2 program3
    @echo "Compilation completed"

program1: program1a

program1 program1a program2 program3:
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

---

**EDIT 2**: The only solution that comes to my mind to avoid dependencies is as follow.

Create 2 separate makefiles like this :

```make
# Makefile1.mk

.NOTPARALLEL: # Force disabling of -j flag

all: program1 program1a

program1 program1a:
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

```make
# Makefile

all: program1 program1a program2 program3

program1 program1a:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile1.mk

program2 program3:
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Comment: You can make this a little cleaner: remove the commands from the first rule, and add `program1` to the list of targets in the second rule.

Comment: This way it's not possible to compile `program1` without compiling `program1a`