# Forcing Orders in Makefile Dependencies

Tags: c, sed, makefile

I need some help writing a GNU makefile. I have a C program "main.c", which is dependent on the value of "CONSTANT" defined in the file "constants.h".

"main.c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "constants.h"

void work(void)
{
    int array[CONSTANT];
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSTANT; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    printf("constant=%d\n", CONSTANT);
    work();
    return 0;
}
```

"constant.h"

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

#define CONSTANT 4
#endif
```

What I'm trying to do here is to compile the program with different values for "CONSTANT". For example, "out1" is compiled with "CONSTANT=1" and with "make all", I should be able to produce all the variants ("out1", "out2" and "out4").

The problem is that "a.o" required by "main.c" also depends on the value of "CONSTANT". So "a.o" must be compiled after "sed%". However, as far as I understand, there is no way in "make" to force orders in dependencies (I guess this is the whole point of using makefiles).

What is the recommended way to address this situation?

"Makefile"

```
CC= gcc
CFLAGS  = -std=c99 -Wall

CONSTANTS = 1 2 4
targets = $(addprefix out, $(CONSTANTS))
seds = $(addprefix sed, $(CONSTANTS))

.PHONY: $(seds)
$(seds): sed%:
  sed -i 's/define CONSTANT [0-9]*/define CONSTANT $*/g' constants.h

$(targets): out%: main.c sed% a.o
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< a.o -o $@

a.o: a.c constant.h
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< a.o -o $@

 .PHONY: all
 all : $(targets)
```

Note that I'm aware that I can rewrite "main.c" so that it takes a parameter from the comman line. In practice, many other files other than "main.c" depend on "CONSTANT", so I want to avoid rewriting all these files. I'm also aware that I can do something like "gcc -DCONSTANT=n main.c", but every file dependent on "CONSTANT" must be recompiled as well.

Related Questions

- [How to specify Makefile target building order without put any physical dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458999/how-to-specify-makefile-target-building-order-without-put-any-physical-dependenc)
- [Force order of dependencies in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529043/force-order-of-dependencies-in-a-makefile)

Comment: Make assumes that once it has built a file (`a.o`), it is up to date and won't need re-recompiling during the same run.  Therefore, you have to do something else.  One option would be to create `a1.o`, `a2.o` and `a4.o` from `a.c` and `constants.h` and suitable sed-work.  If there's only one constant, consider `-DCONSTANT=1` on the command line as you create `a1.o` from `a.c`, etc, without using `constants.h` at all.  However, I suspect that this is a matter of minimization for SO, and you have more values than just the one to set.  I still tend towards creating differently named object files.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with a test. I.e. define a situation (constant.h) changed or a certain way of calling the makefile) and a desired result, i.e. an output or a resulting content of files.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I went for generating separate object files (a1.o, a2.o, ....) as you and Mike suggested. My program has only one constant to configure, so your solution worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm ... aware that I can do something like "gcc -DCONSTANT=n main.c", 
>   but every file dependent on "CONSTANT" must be recompiled as well.

This needn't be a hindrance if you have your makefile generate
the correct `-DCONSTANT=n` and distinct object file in every compilation recipe.

Here's an illustration:

**constants.h**

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

#ifndef CONSTANT
#define CONSTANT 4
#endif

#endif
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "constants.h"

int foo = CONSTANT;
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "constants.h"

extern int foo;

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",CONSTANT + foo);
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -std=c99 -Wall

CONSTANTS = 1 2 4
TARGETS = $(addprefix out, $(CONSTANTS))
SRCS := main.c foo.c

define compile =
$(basename $(1))$(2).o: $(1) constants.h
    $$(CC) -c -DCONSTANT=$(2) $$(CFLAGS) $$< -o $$@
endef

.PHONY: all clean

all : $(TARGETS)

$(foreach src,$(SRCS),\
    $(foreach const,$(CONSTANTS),$(eval $(call compile,$(src),$(const))))) 

out%: main%.o foo%.o 
    $(CC) $^ -o $@


clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS) *.o
```

This runs like:

```
$ make
gcc -c -DCONSTANT=1 -std=c99 -Wall main.c -o main1.o
gcc -c -DCONSTANT=1 -std=c99 -Wall foo.c -o foo1.o
gcc main1.o foo1.o -o out1
gcc -c -DCONSTANT=2 -std=c99 -Wall main.c -o main2.o
gcc -c -DCONSTANT=2 -std=c99 -Wall foo.c -o foo2.o
gcc main2.o foo2.o -o out2
gcc -c -DCONSTANT=4 -std=c99 -Wall main.c -o main4.o
gcc -c -DCONSTANT=4 -std=c99 -Wall foo.c -o foo4.o
gcc main4.o foo4.o -o out4
```

And the resulting programs run like:

```
$ for i in 1 2 4; do ./out$i; done
2
4
8
```

Comment: Separate object files make sense. I got my thing working. Thank you.